# Initializing Date Object in java from a given string representation

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to import a given string representing a Date in the format:

```
2007-03-12T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

Now to create a new Date Object i use Joda Library using:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```

However, i want to make sure two things here:

- How to handle GTM +1 in this date time context?
- Is there anyway,
     that i don't have to parse this string, and the Date Object can be
     initialized directly with this string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.parse("2007-03-12T00:00:00.000+01:00");
```

As has been mentioned in other answers, the offset is supposed to be parsed along with the rest of the string according to the documentation.

Comment: Thankyou that was pretty simple but i never tried assuming it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse that date string using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), then pass that Date into a Joda class:

```
String dateStr = "2007-03-12T00:00:00.000+01:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = sdf.parse( dateStr.replaceAll(":(?=..$)", "")); // remove last colon
```

Note that you must remove the last colon so the offset is a [RFC 822 time zone](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/) like `+0100`, which I did using [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

Both your questions can be answered by reading the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) for the class

timezone is handled by the class. Look for the [constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) which takes the timezone argument.

Yes you can create the DateTime object using the string. [DateTime.parse(String)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) is available to do that. There is also another [method](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29) available to parse custom date formats if required.

Comment: Rather than effectively just saying "RTFM", you could provide an example for the given date string - if for no other reason than to help future visitors who stumble upon this answer.

Comment: @Sean, I have had a look at formatter but i can't understand how can i use timezone in formatter? Also if i have this letter T, then how would i use parse with this? Can you give me some idea?